# Nested JSON parsing using JSONparse()

Tags: javascript, json

I cannot seem to extract the data I want from this (verified) JSON string coming from my home automation server (i.e. I cannot change the JSON return).

```js
var myJson = '{ "Device_Num_6": { "states": [ { "id": 207, "service": "urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SwitchPower1", "variable": "Status", "value": "0" }, { "id": 208, "service": "urn:upnp-org:serviceId:Dimming1", "variable": "LoadLevelTarget", "value": "94" }, { "id": 209, "service": "urn:upnp-org:serviceId:Dimming1", "variable": "LoadLevelStatus", "value": "0" }, { "id": 210, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:HaDevice1", "variable": "Configured", "value": "1" }, { "id": 211, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:HaDevice1", "variable": "ModeSetting", "value": "1:;2:;3:;4:" }, { "id": 212, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:HaDevice1", "variable": "LastUpdate", "value": "1438440091" }, { "id": 213, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:HaDevice1", "variable": "FirstConfigured", "value": "1438440091" }, { "id": 214, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveDevice1", "variable": "Capabilities", "value": "209,140,0,4,17,1,L,R,RS,|38:1,39,112,114,115,134," }, { "id": 215, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveDevice1", "variable": "ManufacturerInfo", "value": "99,17495,12848" }, { "id": 216, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveDevice1", "variable": "VersionInfo", "value": "6,1,91,2,11" }, { "id": 217, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveDevice1", "variable": "NodeInfo", "value": "26,27,70,72,73,86," }, { "id": 218, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveDevice1", "variable": "Neighbors", "value": "1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,21,25,26,27,31,32,33,34,35," }, { "id": 219, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveDevice1", "variable": "LastReset", "value": "0" }, { "id": 220, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveDevice1", "variable": "AssociationNum", "value": "0" }, { "id": 221, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveDevice1", "variable": "LastRouteUpdate", "value": "1468760253" }, { "id": 222, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveDevice1", "variable": "PollOk", "value": "43947" }, { "id": 223, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveDevice1", "variable": "LastNnu", "value": "1468735200,700" }, { "id": 224, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveDevice1", "variable": "LastArr", "value": "1468735200,700" }, { "id": 225, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveDevice1", "variable": "PollNoReply", "value": "54" }, { "id": 226, "service": "urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:ZWaveNetwork1", "variable": "ConsecutivePollFails", "value": "0" } ], "Jobs": [ ], "PendingJobs": 0, "tooltip": { "display": 0 }, "status": -1 }, "Using_2G": 0, "LoadTime": 1468766261, "DataVersion": 766262647, "UserData_DataVersion": 766261013, "TimeStamp": 1468779944, "lights_on": 3, "lights_off": 8, "doors_locked": 5, "doors_unlocked": 2, "sensors_tripped": 0, "sensors_not_tripped": 8, "failed_devices": 8, "visible_devices": 93, "partitions_active": 0, "partitions_notactive": 2, "alerts": [ { "PK_Device": 154, "Room": 10, "DeviceName": "Laundry Door Lock", "DeviceType": "urn:schemas-micasaverde-com:device:DoorLock:1", "PK_Alert": "4742240051", "LocalDate": "2016-07-17 10:38:22", "EventType": 4, "SourceType": 4, "Argument": 0, "Filesize": 0, "Severity": 2, "LocalTimestamp": 1468766302, "Code": "SL_BATTERYALARM", "NewValue": "0", "Description": "Laundry Door Lock", "Users": "", "Server_Storage": "", "Key": "", "Icon": "", "PK_Store": "0" }, { "PK_Device": 150, "Room": 23, "DeviceName": "Kids Bath Motion", "DeviceType": "urn:schemas-micasaverde-com:device:MotionSensor:1", "PK_Alert": "4742240181", "LocalDate": "2016-07-17 10:38:22", "EventType": 4, "SourceType": 4, "Argument": 0, "Filesize": 0, "Severity": 2, "LocalTimestamp": 1468766302, "Code": "SL_BATTERYALARM", "NewValue": "10", "Description": "Kids Bath Motion", "Users": "", "Server_Storage": "", "Key": "", "Icon": "", "PK_Store": "0" }, { "PK_Device": 101, "Room": 21, "DeviceName": "Cabana Door Lock", "DeviceType": "urn:schemas-micasaverde-com:device:DoorLock:1", "PK_Alert": "4742255081", "LocalDate": "2016-07-17 10:40:18", "EventType": 4, "SourceType": 4, "Argument": 0, "Filesize": 0, "Severity": 2, "LocalTimestamp": 1468766418, "Code": "DL_LOW_BATTERY", "NewValue": "1", "Description": "Cabana Door Lock", "Users": "", "Server_Storage": "", "Key": "", "Icon": "", "PK_Store": "0" }, { "PK_Device": 101, "Room": 21, "DeviceName": "Cabana Door Lock", "DeviceType": "urn:schemas-micasaverde-com:device:DoorLock:1", "PK_Alert": "4742255231", "LocalDate": "2016-07-17 10:40:18", "EventType": 4, "SourceType": 4, "Argument": 0, "Filesize": 0, "Severity": 3, "LocalTimestamp": 1468766418, "Code": "DL_LOCK_CHANGED", "NewValue": "3", "Description": "Cabana Door Lock", "Users": "", "Server_Storage": "", "Key": "", "Icon": "", "PK_Store": "0" }, { "PK_Device": 101, "Room": 21, "DeviceName": "Cabana Door Lock", "DeviceType": "urn:schemas-micasaverde-com:device:DoorLock:1", "PK_Alert": "4742255371", "LocalDate": "2016-07-17 10:40:18", "EventType": 4, "SourceType": 4, "Argument": 0, "Filesize": 0, "Severity": 3, "LocalTimestamp": 1468766418, "Code": "DL_CODE_CHANGED", "NewValue": "3", "Description": "Cabana Door Lock", "Users": "", "Server_Storage": "", "Key": "", "Icon": "", "PK_Store": "0" }, { "PK_Device": 101, "Room": 21, "DeviceName": "Cabana Door Lock", "DeviceType": "urn:schemas-micasaverde-com:device:DoorLock:1", "PK_Alert": "4742255471", "LocalDate": "2016-07-17 10:40:18", "EventType": 4, "SourceType": 4, "Argument": 0, "Filesize": 0, "Severity": 3, "LocalTimestamp": 1468766418, "Code": "DL_USERCODE", "NewValue": "UserID=\"1\" UserName=\"Main\"", "Description": "Cabana Door Lock", "Users": "", "Server_Storage": "", "Key": "", "Icon": "", "PK_Store": "0" }, { "PK_Device": 101, "Room": 21, "DeviceName": "Cabana Door Lock", "DeviceType": "urn:schemas-micasaverde-com:device:DoorLock:1", "PK_Alert": "4742255591", "LocalDate": "2016-07-17 10:40:18", "EventType": 4, "SourceType": 4, "Argument": 0, "Filesize": 0, "Severity": 3, "LocalTimestamp": 1468766418, "Code": "DL_LOCK_BUTTON", "NewValue": "1", "Description": "Cabana Door Lock", "Users": "", "Server_Storage": "", "Key": "", "Icon": "", "PK_Store": "0" }, { "PK_Device": 101, "Room": 21, "DeviceName": "Cabana Door Lock", "DeviceType": "urn:schemas-micasaverde-com:device:DoorLock:1", "PK_Alert": "4742255721", "LocalDate": "2016-07-17 10:40:18", "EventType": 4, "SourceType": 4, "Argument": 0, "Filesize": 0, "Severity": 1, "LocalTimestamp": 1468766418, "Code": "DL_LOCK_FAILURE", "NewValue": "1", "Description": "Cabana Door Lock", "Users": "", "Server_Storage": "", "Key": "", "Icon": "", "PK_Store": "0" }, { "PK_Device": 101, "Room": 21, "DeviceName": "Cabana Door Lock", "DeviceType": "urn:schemas-micasaverde-com:device:DoorLock:1", "PK_Alert": "4742255801", "LocalDate": "2016-07-17 10:40:18", "EventType": 4, "SourceType": 4, "Argument": 0, "Filesize": 0, "Severity": 1, "LocalTimestamp": 1468766418, "Code": "DL_PINFAILED", "NewValue": "1", "Description": "Cabana Door Lock", "Users": "", "Server_Storage": "", "Key": "", "Icon": "", "PK_Store": "0" }, { "PK_Device": 101, "Room": 21, "DeviceName": "Cabana Door Lock", "DeviceType": "urn:schemas-micasaverde-com:device:DoorLock:1", "PK_Alert": "4742255971", "LocalDate": "2016-07-17 10:40:18", "EventType": 4, "SourceType": 4, "Argument": 0, "Filesize": 0, "Severity": 2, "LocalTimestamp": 1468766418, "Code": "SL_BATTERYALARM", "NewValue": "0", "Description": "Cabana Door Lock", "Users": "", "Server_Storage": "", "Key": "", "Icon": "", "PK_Store": "0" } ], "ZWaveStatus": 1, "Mode": 1, "LocalTime": "2016-07-17 14:25:44 D" }';

var myObject = JSON.parse(myJson);

console.log(myObject.Device_Num_6.states[0].id);  // should return 207
```

Comment: How are you getting the JSON in your script?  You need to escape the backslashes with an extra backslash.  The JSON is perfectly valid on its own.  The problem happened when you pasted it in your script.  If you're fetching the data via AJAX or something, this problem won't occur.

Comment: Ahhh... Yes, it should be properly escaped if I'm using this literal example. Yes, my goal is to request data via Ajax. I thought that I'd get the scripts sorted prior to working the Ajax calls!

Answer (score 0):

Your json has invalid format. Because of that you couldn't to parse it as `JSON.parse` method. Try to check it here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

**UPD:** issue with this string `"NewValue": "UserID=\"1\" UserName=\"Main\""`. You should make it as  `"NewValue": "UserID=\\"1\\" UserName=\\"Main\\""`

Comment: Try to add more relevant details than just including the link.

Comment: @Brad, absolutely agree with you. But before parsing you so big json file you should verify it on valid. In this case issue in this file was in encoding string

Comment: @Alex Filatov, that was exactly my problem, I did validate the JSON string via <link>jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com</link>.  Shame on me (a C++ person) for not considering escaping the backward leaning slashes!